# Prove the following sequence diverges to infinity using the definition of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Prove that the $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^2+1}{4n-1} = \infty $.

From the definition of convergence we have to prove that:

$\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists X \in \mathbb{R}, \forall n > X, |\frac{n^2+1}{4n-1}-\infty | < \epsilon $.

When we use a number that is in the set of real numbers, then it is easy to combine the numbers together using algebra and then find a value of n >$ \epsilon$ however i am unsure what to do with the $\infty$ here.

Comment: No, divergence to infinity means that $\forall M>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n\geq N$, $u_n\geq M$.

Comment: Yes, but i want to use a direct proof using the definition of convergence

Comment: Using the definition of convergence when you want to prove divergence is not a very good idea. Except if you use a proof by contradiction, but that's not what you tried. Substracting infinity does not make sense.

Comment: I know, it's a homework question, and i'm just unsure where to begin!

Comment: The statement you are trying to prove isn't quite right.  Try this.

$\forall M>0, \exists N>0$ such that $n>N\implies f(n) > M$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:**

To find a lower bound for a ratio, it is enough to find a lower bound for the numerator and an upper bound for the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

The definition you have used
is the definition of convergence
to a *finite* limit.

As Augustin and Doug M have commented,
the definition of divergence
to infinity is different,
and is the definition they have stated.

So,
use that definition.